# Should I use only a service for all my controllers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I created a service in angular, that is like:

```
function dbService($http) {
    var instance = '';

    var service = {
        add: add,
        instance: instance
    };
    
    return service;

    function add(object) {
        return $http.post('/api/' + this.instance, object);
    }
}
```

I only change the instance attribute in every call to the service, because I notice that every Service has the same configuration but only changes the controller name. Some like:

```
$scope.send() = function() {
    dbService.instance="Cars";
   
    dbService.add($scope.car).then(
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

What kind of problem can give me this approach? Should I create one service for every Controller (something like "CarsService" and so on), or should I continue with this approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The use of dbService singleton object is a mistake here. There should be multiple object instances. They should either be different services (which doesn't make sense for current service that has no logic but `add` method but will make sense when it's responsible for handling the response, as it should be in proper MVC/MVVM). Or `dbService` can become `dbServiceFactory` and return a class or object instance when being used in a controller, e.g. `var carDbService = dbServiceFactory('car')` (it depends on what you need because carDbService won't be a singleton in different controllers).

Answer (score 0):

One service is enough to all controllers. I used following service without any problem.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
var HttpServiceApp = angular.module('app');


var Http = function($http) {

  var HttpObject = {};

  HttpObject.get = function(route) {
    return $http.get(route)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });
  };

  HttpObject.post = function(route, data) {
    // console.log(data);
    return $http.post(route, data).then(function(responce) {
      // console.log("response :: " + JSON.stringify(responce));
      return responce.data;
    });
  };



  HttpObject.getParams = function(route, params) {
    var requestData = {
      method: "GET",
      url: route,
      params: params
    };

    return HttpObject.request(requestData);
  };


  HttpObject.request = function(request_data) {
    return $http(request_data).then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  };

  return HttpObject;

};

HttpServiceApp.factory('Http', ['$http', Http]);
})();
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.send() = function(){

                   Http.post("api/Cars",$scope.car).then(
                   function(data){
                         console.log(data);
                   },
                  function(error){
                         console.log(error);
                   }
                 };
```

Answer (score 0):

@estus are in right.Although I do not know the specific use case, suspect that using a single service is not the best solution.

I would recommend looking [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular). With this library you can define a service for each resource (endpoint) that encapsulate the API logic.
Apply to your example with restangular:

- Define the resource: Cars (you can extend with custom methods)
- Inject it on the controllers that need use it.

With this aproach your code match better the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and also more readable and easy to understand.

**cars.resource.js**

```
angular.module('resources')
    .factory('Cars', CarsFactory);

function CarsFactory(Restangular, API_ENDPOINT) {
    return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
        RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl(API_ENDPOINT);

        RestangularConfigurer.extendModel('cars', function(model) {
             //Extend the resource with custom funcions
             model.getParts = function() {
                return model.getList('parts');
            };
            return model;
        });
    }).service('cars');
  }
})();
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('myapp',[resources])
    .controller('MyCtrl',['$scope','Cars', MyCtrlFunction]);

function MyCtrlFunction($scope, Cars]) {
  $scope.send() = function(){
     Cars.save($scope.car).then (...)

  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The service is a singleton; you don't have seperate instances of it no need for an `instance` property.
You don't realy need to store any state here so just use pure functions:

```
function dbService($http) {

    var service = {
        add: add,
    };

    return service;

    function add(objectType, object) {
        return $http.post('/api/' + objectType, object);
    }
```

}